# JasperReports Breaking with IndexOutOfBoundsException on Fixed String Data input (Java/Gradle Built)

Tags: java, gradle, jasper-reports, indexoutofboundsexception

I am having a Problem with Jasper Reports PDF generation in my Java Spring App.

**Versions**:

- Java 8
- Spring 4.3.3
- Libraries:

  - olap4j 1.2.0
  - jasperreports 6.11.0
  - itextpdf 5.5.13.1

Jasper Files built with the [jasperreports-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/gmazelier/gradle-jasperreports) version 0.3.2

```xml
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.11.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.11.0-0c4056ccaa4d25a5a8c45672d2f764ea3498bebb  -->
...
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="2" y="161" width="582" height="9" uuid="c39550b8-8786-424e-ae97-54db0f570a05"/>
                <box padding="3">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Liberation Sans" size="6" isItalic="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Oblique" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{String_Input}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
...
```

When I comment out the above code snippet from my jrxml file it works for all examples I have setup. However when I add this back it works for all except for one, in which case it gives the following stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [orderInvoice] in context with path [/orderInvoice] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0] with root cause
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStructureTreeRoot.nodeProcess(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStructureTreeRoot.nodeProcess(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStructureTreeRoot.nodeProcess(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStructureTreeRoot.buildTree(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.getCatalog(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.close(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.close(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.Document.close(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:941)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:547)
    [exporter.exportReport();]
    [buildInvoicePDF(response, result);]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This does not make sense as something that should happen sometimes, and not all the time. The string that is passed in is hard coded in the code as a way to manage any updates, but this feels more like a configuration issue over a jrxml issue given this bit of code has been stable for over a year, and does not act up in normal changes. I have unified the JasperReport library used to build the jrxml's. I checked each version to try to figure out what is wrong, and could use either a fix or ideas for how to find a fix. I have not found anything on google or any obvious issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was a product of some cleanup I performed on the app in question.

The original designed included some tagging to make the PDF ADA compliant since it used an old version of Jasper Reports. I removed this to resolve some stability issues, but had a new set of stability issues (see question).

The issue was with this bit of code:

```java
SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
configuration.setTagged(true);
```

This `true` is needed to support these added tags, but with them removed this is causing trouble, so this becomes:

```java
SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
configuration.setTagged(false);
```